# C# chrome driver only opening as background process on IIS / Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running chromedriver on windows server 2016 with IIS, i have my test project installed and invoking it with an MVC5 API. That all seems fine but chromedriver and chrome.exe only seems to open as a background processes.

The same code opens these fine locally, i am not using any of the driver flags for headless browsing either. if i return the drive page source i can see that chromedriver went to google and returned the correct html in my API.

It just does not work for normal / non headless tests with google or our application.

```
        var driver = x.StartWebDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

        return driver.PageSource;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I use

    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl);

with success.

Comment: On IIS on windows server?

Comment: I haven't had any issues with it opening headless for me. Pops right up in the foreground.

Comment: let me know if that works for you,  if so I'll set it as an answer

Comment: I was wondering if you ever found a resolution to this issue? I too have a similar, if not the same problem, where creating a ChromeDriver locally in my web project opens Chrome with the UI, and tests execute correctly. However, when the web application is running on the web server, the chrome.exe processes (chromedriver.exe is executed as well) only seem to run in the background, with no UI, and the tests fail.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @gilliduck perhaps you are using IIS express. For IIs 8 and above the process runs on background!

Comment: @Daniel, resurrecting the dead I see. Regardless, I don't see what IIS has anything to do with this. You instantiating a new chrome webdriver and navigating to page (in the example and in my usages, an external page at that). I've used selenium plenty on boxes without IIS and navigated to external pages that I have no control over with the exact behavior I'm expecting.

Comment: @gilliduck yep indeed back from the dead lol! Well take a look at this answer: https://forums.iis.net/post/2124929.aspx 
this guy wanted to open a desktop application on IIS server, but as mentioned above in the link (answer) this is not possible as IIS runs on a different session and will not show any thing on users desktop!

Comment: The same guy who made the question, says it's possible to do it in IIS Express: https://forums.iis.net/post/2124940.aspx as IIS express can run on the same User Session!

Comment: @gilliduck Even that the application doens't shows up on the desktop, yes it works ok, but sometimes it does not, or at least you can't see what's is going wrong! For me I´m getting errors like "Couldn't click the object at (x,y)" And that´s because the window is not showing or "something else"

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same issue and this is how I solve this:

1. Open a command prompt and navigate to your ChromeDriver location.
2. Execute chromedriver.exe and you will see the message as below.
   [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfp38.png)

   *In the image above you see chrome driver is listening on port 9515.*
3. Now change your code as below, rebuild and call you api to execute your test.

   **ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();**

   //set your chromeoptions here

   **Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:**9515**");

   **_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, options);**

Answer (score 1):

Open the chrome driver and note the port number(eg:5353)

In java:

System.setProperty(chromeDriverName, chromeDriverLocation);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

URL uri = new URL(chromeDriverPort);//http://localhost:5353

WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, options);

your problem gets solved in is server.